# Handling multiple similar expectations

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, promise, protractor

On one of the application pages we have a button bar with a set of different buttons which *change their "enabledness" based on different actions in the screen*.

Hence, a corresponding UI test has quite similar expectation checks, for example:

```
it("action 1", function () {
    // some actions

    expect(pageObject.batch.applyButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
    expect(pageObject.batch.resetButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
    expect(pageObject.batch.refreshQueueButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
    expect(pageObject.batch.dismissButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
});

it("action 2", function () {
    // some actions

    expect(pageObject.batch.applyButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(false);
    expect(pageObject.batch.resetButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
    expect(pageObject.batch.refreshQueueButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(false);
    expect(pageObject.batch.dismissButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
});

it("action 3", function () {
    // some actions

    expect(pageObject.batch.applyButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(false);
    expect(pageObject.batch.resetButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(false);
    expect(pageObject.batch.refreshQueueButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
    expect(pageObject.batch.dismissButton.isEnabled()).toEqual(true);
});
```

This definitely does not look good and violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

How would you refactor it and apply multiple expectation checks in a more readable fashion?

---

I was thinking to have a Page Object function responsible for reporting the state of the buttons that would return a promise resolving into an array of booleans that would actually be asserted in the test:

```
expect(pageObject.batch.getButtonState()).toEqual([true, true, false, false]);
```

It "extracts the method" and helps to make a test shorter, but it makes the debugging harder cutting down on the assertion error information. E.g. `[true, false, true, false] is not equal to [true, true, false, false]` would not mean much and would require separate investigation that could be time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like user943702's answer better, but if you want to keep the look of the array of booleans you could also use:

```
expect(pageObject.batch).toHaveStates([true, true, false, false]);
```

And have the toHaveStates matcher iterate through both arrays and compare each item in the batch in order.

Answer (score 2):

**[custom_matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/custom_matcher.html)**

> Often a project will want to encapsulate custom matching code for use across multiple specs. Here is how to create a Jasmine-compatible custom matcher.

```
// Custom matchers
var matchers = {
  toBeEnabled: { ..

// Register matchers
jasmine.addMatchers(matchers)

it(..
  expect([ .. ]).toBeEnabled()     // pass if ALL enabled
  expect([ .. ]).not.toBeEnabled() // pass if ALL disabled
```